# can FormMixin be used in TemplateView?

Tags: django

Hi i've used FormMixin in DetailView but I would also like to implement it in TemplateView if that isn't possible how can I implement a form in TemplateView

Comment: Yes, you could the `FormMixin` with `TemplateView`, e.g. `class MyView(FormMixin, TemplateView)`, but I would use [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) instead.

Comment: So do you mean you would use FormView and include  def get_context_data() to cater for the rest of the content incase you need to add some other models to the page? @Alasdair

Comment: Yes, that sounds right